# Cross-browser alternative to CSS :has pseudo-class

Tags: css, firefox, css-selectors, cross-browser, pseudo-class

I am looking for a cross-browser compatible CSS selector to prevent body scrolling when a modal is opened.

Currently, I am using the CSS `:has` pseudo-class with the selector:

```css
body:has(dialog.active) {
  /* prevent scroll stuff*/
}
```

However, this selector is not supported in Firefox.

Is there an alternative CSS selector that can achieve the same result? Please note that I am unable to add or modify any JavaScript or HTML on the page, so the solution must be purely CSS-based.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there was an alternative selector which could achieve the same result, then why would we need `:has`? There is no alternative selector.

The way we’ve displayed dialogs in the past is to cover the screen with an absolutely positioned, partially transparent `<div>`, then have the dialog appear inside that, or in front of that. This can prevent people **clicking** on the page behind the dialog. Not sure if it can prevent **scrolling** — I’ve not looked into that.

My recommendation is to use `:has` anyway. Firefox will add support eventually, and in the meantime your webpage will still be usable in Firefox, just not as usable as you’d like it to be. Firefox’s [market share](https://gs.statcounter.com/browser-market-share) is only 3%.

Comment: :has is genius… and still an open issue today with Firefox.  At least for me - a major issue, which leads that I recommend people to just change the browser. I don't understand Mozillas strategy... it gets more and more to be a "modern" IE

Comment: @Adrian — Mozilla's strategy is "Not releasing a feature until it actually works". `:has` is **hard** to implement.

Answer (score 4):

Support for **:has** is available from Firefox 120 version nightly build and soon will be available for use. Here is the test link

https://wpt.fyi/results/css/selectors/dir-pseudo-in-has.html?label=master&label=experimental&aligned&q=label%3Ainterop-2023-pseudos

Here is the official release notes from Firefox Nightly 120.0a1, you can find note part of Web platform section(#3).

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/120.0a1/releasenotes/

> Starting with Firefox 119, the :has() selector is now available in
> nightly builds. This allows authors to match elements that has, or
> "anchors", at least one element matching its relative selector.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for regarding release